# SwipeRefresherLayout nullpointer

Tags: android, android-layout, swiperefreshlayout

I want to have an SwipeRefreshLayout in my ScrollingActivity, so I include the following xml as my content.

But when I start the app I get following exception and I have absolutly no idea whats wrong with it. The ID is right, the SwipeRefresherLayout is there ... maybe because it's in a ScrollingActivity? or Included?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.corestudio.coinmaster/de.corestudio.coinmaster.PocketMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout$OnRefreshListener)' on a null object reference
    at de.corestudio.coinmaster.PocketMain.onCreate(PocketMain.java:201)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Main.java

```
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
swipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.pocketMainRefresh);

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new 

SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

    }
});
```

include.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pocketMainRefresh"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".PocketMain"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_pocket_main">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_placeholder_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Füge ein neues Item hinzu"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_placeholder_recyclervie"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerviewPocketItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="gone">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_placeholder_recyclervie"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/add_icon"
        tools:visibility="visible" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In which activity's lifecycle method did you put this code?

Comment: @Wang its in the MainActivity, and this activity is a scrollingactivity so with appbar. Maybe its because of that?

Comment: why are you nesting your constraintLayout to SwipeRefresherLayout ?

Comment: @scienticious when the recyclerviewadapter is empty some other content will be shown. But even without the constraint and only the recyclerview it's the same exception

Comment: @J.Doe From the logs, seems like the crash is happening at an activity called PocketMain. Do you have 2 activities by any chance?

Comment: @RishabhJain PocketMain.java is the mainactivity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @MartinZeitler it's just wrong because? If you're answering it would be nice if you are explaining why it is wrong instead of just saying "is just wrong" it's not helpfull

Comment: @J.Doe most likely it cannot find `@+id/pocketMainRefresh` inside the `include`... what I've previously thought that was wrong was just misunderstood due to to poor code-indention...not certain, but moving the `include` inside the  `AppBarLayout` might be worth a try (in case it doesn't lay out as it should).

Comment: Well it can find the textview, the imageview ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `id` attribute from the `include` ...

or wrap the `SwipeRefreshLayout` into a `<layout>` node.

because it's `id` attribute might be overwritten on merge.

Comment: Thank you, removing the id made it.

Answer (score 0):

where are you including **SwipeRefreshlayout** , you can use simply like this :
first of all define your swipeRefreshLayout in xml file .

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/pull_to_Refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_marginTop_five"
            android:background="@drawable/help_box_bg"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_three">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layout_marginBottom_ten">


                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclearView_outletlist"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

after defining your **xml** file come to the java file

**implements on class header**

```
    SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener,
    SwipeRefreshLayout pulltoRefresh;
    pulltoRefresh = view.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_Refresh);
    pulltoRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(this);


   @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

     // do here what do you want
     }
```

Comment: I use the SwipeRefreshLayout in the MainActivitiy, it gets included.